# Finding the most frequent character in a string and repeat this for millions of strings quickly

Tags: c#

I need to iterate through a couple million essays that are about 500 words long and for every essay & I have to return the character is repeated the most.

I have the following code but to iterate through 1 million essay (I have the same essay hard coded). It takes almost three minutes before it has a collection of all the popular characters from each essay.

How can I optimize this to be faster? If you have another method besides my `GetMostFrequentCharacter()`, please suggest something w/ sample.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var popularCharacters = new List<char[]>();
        var EssayCount = 0;
        var start = DateTime.Now;
        const int noOfEssays = 1000000;

        Console.WriteLine("Looking for most popular characters in {0} articles: ", noOfEssays);

        // Gen 1,000,000 essays
        for (int i = 0; i < noOfEssays; i++)
        {

            var anEssay = "At the time, the law had relatively few beneficiaries—people under 26 covered by their parents’ health plans, a small population of people with pre-existing medical conditions. But some of them had already used their new coverage to finance the kinds of life-saving treatments that would leave them in need of chronic care for the rest of their lives. Take away the health law, and most of these organ transplant recipients and other patients would have become unable to afford their medications, and some of them would die. Since then, millions of people have gained coverage under the law, and that group of chronic care patients has grown much larger. But despite the fact that the Court upheld the law, and President Obama won reelection, the ACA isn’t out of danger. On Friday, the Supreme Court agreed to hear a case that will determine whether the federal government can continue to subsidize private ACA coverage in states that didn’t set up their own insurance exchanges. That case is King v. Burwell, but the issue at stake has come to be defined by a comparable case called Halbig v. Burwell. The Fourth Circuit Court of Appeals ruled against the challengers in King, but the Supreme Court agreed to grant cert to those challengers anyhow, despite the absence of a Circuit Court split. If the five conservative Supreme Court justices are so inclined, they can void ACA subsidies for millions of beneficiaries, and cripple the insurance markets in about three dozen states. Some of those beneficiaries will be the kinds of transplant recipients and other patients I wrote about three and a half years ago. Except today there are many more of them. Several of these patients explained the risk to their lives in an amicus brief, urging a different circuit court to reject the challenge to the subsidies, and thus to the viability of the insurance markets their lives depend on. Without insurance, Jennifer [Causor’s] treatments would be completely unaffordable. Her transplant cost nearly $280,000. She takes three anti-rejection drugs, one of which has a sticker price of $2,400 per month…. Should she become uninsured, Jennifer would face bankruptcy and even death.".Replace(" ","");

            popularCharacters.Add(anEssay.GetMostFrequentCharacter().ToArray());                
        }

        var end = DateTime.Now;

        Console.WriteLine("Time to process {0} Essays: " + (end - start), noOfEssays);
        Console.WriteLine("Hit enter to write output: ");
        Console.ReadLine();


        foreach (char[] popularCharacter in popularCharacters)
        {
            EssayCount++;
            if (popularCharacter.Count() > 1)
            {                    
                Console.WriteLine("Essay {0}: Most popular chr & equal in freq: ", EssayCount);
                foreach (char c in popularCharacter)
                Console.Write(c + ", ");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.Write("Essay {0}: Most frequent chr: ", EssayCount);
                Console.WriteLine(popularCharacter);
            }  
        }
        Console.WriteLine();            
    }
}

static class Utilities
{

    public static IEnumerable<T> GetMostFrequentCharacter<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input)
    {
        var dict = input.ToLookup(x => x);
        if (dict.Count == 0)
            return Enumerable.Empty<T>();
        var maxCount = dict.Max(x => x.Count<T>());
        return dict.Where(x => x.Count<T>() == maxCount).Select(x => x.Key);
    }
}
```

Comment: Make an array of 128 bytes; for each character c in the string, increment the c'th element of the array. Then loop through the array and return the maximum.

Answer (score 3):

**Some thoughts**

- The method should not be generic because the methods name `GetMostFrequentCharacter` implies that it returns some kind of `Char`
- The method should be renamed to `GetMostFrequentCharacters` as it returns an `IEnumerable`.
- The variable `dict` should be renamed to `lookup`
- The check if `input` contains any elements should be done before the call of `ToLookup()`

After considering these your method looks like

```
public static IEnumerable<Char> GetMostFrequentCharacters(this IEnumerable<Char> input)
{
    if (!input.Any()) { return Enumerable.Empty<Char>(); }

    var lookup = input.ToLookup(x => x);
    var maxCount = lookup.Max(x => x.Count<Char>());

    return lookup.Where(x => x.Count<Char>() == maxCount).Select(x => x.Key);
}
```

If it is possible to limt the charset to `ASCII` you could gain big speed improvement by using [raporttech97](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/23315/raptortech97) idea from the [comments](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/69296/finding-the-most-frequent-character-in-a-string-and-repeat-this-for-millions-of#comment126586_69296)

```
public static IEnumerable<Char> GetMostFrequentCharacters(this IEnumerable<Char> input)
{
    if (!input.Any()) { return Enumerable.Empty<Char>(); }

    const int maxChar = 128;
    int[] histogram = new int[maxChar];

    foreach (char c in input)
    {
        if (c > maxChar) { continue; }
        histogram[c] = histogram[c] + 1;

    }

    IList<Char> mostFrequentChars = new List<Char>();

    int max = int.MinValue;

    for (int i = 33; i < histogram.Length; i++)
    {
        if (histogram[i] > max)
        {
            max = histogram[i];
            mostFrequentChars.Clear();
            mostFrequentChars.Add((char)i);

        }
        else if (histogram[i] == max)
        {
            mostFrequentChars.Add((char)i);
        }
    }

    return mostFrequentChars;
}
```

This is about 4 times faster than your solution.
Timed on my computer for 1.000.000 calls

Yours: 90 seconds
This: 24 seconds

Comment: I imagine it's generic because it's written as an extension method of `IEnumerable`, which must therefore be generic. You are right that it should not be there, because it should really be an extension method of `string`

Answer (score 2):

Your `GetMostFrequentCharacter` method seems robust to me, but the overall performance can be greatly improved by multi-threading the algorithm.

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For<List<char[]>>(0, noOfEssays,

        //initialize thread-local intermediate list to store results in.
        () => new List<char[]>(),

        //main loop body
        (i, loop, popChars) =>
        {
           var anEssay = "At the time, the law had relatively few beneficiaries—people under 26 covered by their parents’ health plans, a small population of people with pre-existing medical conditions. But some of them had already used their new coverage to finance the kinds of life-saving treatments that would leave them in need of chronic care for the rest of their lives. Take away the health law, and most of these organ transplant recipients and other patients would have become unable to afford their medications, and some of them would die. Since then, millions of people have gained coverage under the law, and that group of chronic care patients has grown much larger. But despite the fact that the Court upheld the law, and President Obama won reelection, the ACA isn’t out of danger. On Friday, the Supreme Court agreed to hear a case that will determine whether the federal government can continue to subsidize private ACA coverage in states that didn’t set up their own insurance exchanges. That case is King v. Burwell, but the issue at stake has come to be defined by a comparable case called Halbig v. Burwell. The Fourth Circuit Court of Appeals ruled against the challengers in King, but the Supreme Court agreed to grant cert to those challengers anyhow, despite the absence of a Circuit Court split. If the five conservative Supreme Court justices are so inclined, they can void ACA subsidies for millions of beneficiaries, and cripple the insurance markets in about three dozen states. Some of those beneficiaries will be the kinds of transplant recipients and other patients I wrote about three and a half years ago. Except today there are many more of them. Several of these patients explained the risk to their lives in an amicus brief, urging a different circuit court to reject the challenge to the subsidies, and thus to the viability of the insurance markets their lives depend on. Without insurance, Jennifer [Causor’s] treatments would be completely unaffordable. Her transplant cost nearly $280,000. She takes three anti-rejection drugs, one of which has a sticker price of $2,400 per month…. Should she become uninsured, Jennifer would face bankruptcy and even death.".Replace(" ","");
           popChars.Add(anEssay.GetMostFrequentCharacter().ToArray());
           return popChars;
        },

        //combine all thread-local lists to the main list.
        popChars => { lock (popularCharacters) popularCharacters.AddRange(popChars);}               
    );
```

On my machine, this change reduces the required time from **98.0s** to **16.0s** - x6.125 speedup.

Also, you should not use `DateTime.Now` for benchmarking because it is not incredibly accurate, rather use the `StopWatch` class.